# Confused Java Threadpool and synchroized methods

Tags: java, multithreading

I am a little bit confused about the behavior of each "task" that I want to execute with my Thread pool. I have an assignment to read data from CSV file(row by row), and I need to do it in a multi-threaded way, to can see below the implementation so far:

```
public class CSVParser implements Runnable
{
    private String m_csvFilePath = "C:/Users/Gabi/Desktop/HttpTrafficProject/CSVfile.csv";
    private BufferedReader m_bReader = null;
    private String m_Line = "";
    private String m_CSVSplitBy = ",";
    private String m_SrcIP = "";
    private String m_Host = "";
    private String m_Request = "";
    private String m_UserAgent = "";

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            m_bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.m_csvFilePath));
            while((m_Line = m_bReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] str = m_Line.split(m_CSVSplitBy);
                m_SrcIP = str[0];
                m_Host = str[1];
                m_Request = str[2];
                m_UserAgent = str[3];
                System.out.println(this.m_SrcIP +" " + this.m_Host);
            }
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}

public class Main 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Runnable parser = new CSVParser();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
                {
                    executor.execute(parser);
                }

    }

}
```

As I understood executor according to my code, I will have always 3 working threads that each of them will do 5 tasks (correct me if I am wrong).

My question is:

each thread that reads data from CSV file will read all the data and only after finishing doing it another thread will start to read data from the CSV?

Comment: Each thread is synchronized on itself.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What did you expect to happen, what happens that you do not expect? Your threads are not going to work together because of your synchronization, but I'm not sure that this is what you are asking about.

Comment: Each thread is doing something by reading from the csv file and after one thread finishes it another thread continuing a remained part. That's all that you can do by choosing appropriate executor.

Comment: i want that number of thread will read my csv file simultaneously without synchrize run method, by triyng to do that i got StackOverFlowException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread pool contains a number of threads (3 in your example) running in parallel. By calling `executor.execute(parser);` you order the thread pool to execute your `Runnable` (in your case a `CSVParser` instance). The thread pool will do that when it has a free thread available.

You want to execute 1 `CSVParser` instance 5 times with a thread pool having 3 threads. That means the thread pool will start the same `CSVParser` instance three times in parallel. Due to the `synchronized` statement two of the threads will be blocked. So you will always have two threads of your executors blocked (which does not make any sense).

If you remove the `synchronized` statement you will get severe problems because three threads are accessing the same `m_bReader` in parallel.

If you want to have three parallel `CVSParser` you need execute distinct `CVSParser` instances:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
       // add 5 instances of CSVParser
       executor.execute(new CSVParser());
    }

}
```